# VMWare Workstation connection problems

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation, troubleshooting

Our old setup (which worked):

On workstation W-1 (WinXP - 64bit) we had two virtual machines (VMWare 6.5) V-1 and V-2 (both with WinXP-32).

All of them had a different IP static address, V-1 and V-2 were bridged to the W-1's NIC. V-1, V-2 and W-1 were/are in a domain with DNS servers S-1 and S-2.

We could open both V-1 and V-2 and see the W-1, S-1, S-2 and all the network (ping, file share etc.).

After a while (in which I was away from this job) I found the following: VMWare upgraded to 7.1, an installation of VirtualBox (dunno if it has something to do with our theme), the settings from V-1, V-2 and W-1 untouched(?) and the following 'weird' situation:

**Only the first VM can access the network.** IOW, if I start the V-1 I can see (ping, filesharing etc.) W-1, S-1 and the entire LAN. If *after this* I start V-2 from V-2 I can see *only* the W-1. Any other ping (including to the S-1) gives an 'Request time out'.

Similarily, if I start first the V-2 and after this the V-1, then the V-2 works ok in LAN while V-1 does not (it sees only its host system).

Any clues how to have *simultaneously* both virtual machines to work on our LAN?

TIA for any feedback,

John

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the assigned MAC addresses of both instances to ensure that they are not somehow the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. However the *ipconfig /all* shows different physical addresses.

Comment: You might try deleting the virtual NIC definitions and recreating them?